# How to arrange components / pages in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-template

I am going to start a new project with Angular 5 (I am also just learned it for a months before starting this project). 
I have the following design :
[image: Admin > Clients > Edit Clients]

[image: Account > Transactions > List]

Let me explain:
We have main menu on top (Admin, config, Account and Report)
and also the Siderbar of each main menu.

if we click admin the sidebar on left will show Users, Clients, Banks and Groups.

The first picture will highlight the admin & clients as it use Client Component / Page. If I click Banks, ADMIN will still highlighted and Banks will be highlighted.

But when I click [Account], the side bar will be changed to show Transactions, Clients, List and Help page. 
Afaik, I just knew we can have only one template in app.component.html. 
But I need to have different sidebar for different pages. Should I hard coded the sidebar ? or is there any good rules for this ?

2. How to highlight the Admin & Clients if page going to Clients page (I can have url like http://myproject.com/admin/clients/list)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Sidebar component that has dynamic items and depending on what is selected you send them as input and display them. When one of them is selected you output an event with the selected item and handle that in the parent component/container.

This sidebar can either be placed in the app component or in each page, for example if it's required only in some of them and others might have different components there.

For highlighting the active items one can use the [RouterLinkActive directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) or where some more complex is needed create a function to check the url, something like:

```
    isRouteActive(route: string) {
        return this.router.url.includes(route);
    }
```